# Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array

Tags: theming

```
function theme_test($form) {

  $output = '';

  foreach($form['field'] as $key => $val){

    $output .= '<div class="test">';
    $output .= drupal_render($val['uid'. $key]);
    $output .= '</div>';
    unset($key,$val);
  }

  return $output;

}
```

When I run this code, I get the following warning message:

> Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in theme_test()

How do I resolve this, and what is the reason behind this warning?

Comment: You should add more information, especially why you expect `$val` to be an array. As it is, it's more a question about PHP, and not a question specific for Drupal. The meaning of the warning doesn't change, in Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

There's somehting funky happening on this line:

```
$output .= drupal_render($val['uid'. $key]);
```

$val is not an array, you'll need to rethink your PHP code. Do a Google search for "Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array" and you'll see a bunch of cases where other users are dealing with the same issue. As an example:

[PHP : Cannot use a scalar value as an array](http://www.lost-in-code.com/platforms/wordpress/php-cannot-use-a-scalar-value-as-an-array/)

EDIT:

Looking at your code again, this line looks suspect:

```
unset($key,$val);
```

You're in a loop that is using these values. Applying an unset could result in the issue in addition to the point I made above.

Comment: That is true: Using `unset($key,$val);` is completely useless; it would be like unsetting the local variables used in a function before it returns the control back to the caller function.